# Creating a copy of a file with same name + current date

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to save workbook at a different location with same name + current date.

I am able to copy file at other location but with different name using:

```
Sub Backup()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\mani\Desktop\reference_files\AutoGenerated.xlsx"
End Sub
```

I am not getting how to keep the file name same as existing one by adding current date to it.

For example, the file name is "abc.xlsx" then I want to save this file at "C:\Users\mani\Desktop\reference_files" with name "abc_26May2017.xlsx".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current workbook name (including path) using its `FullName` property, and you can format the date using the `Format` function.

```
Sub Backup()
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveCopyAs Left(.FullName, InstrRev(.FullName, ".") - 1) & _
                    "_" & Format(Date(), "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If you need to use a different path, you can use the workbook's `Name` property:

```
Sub Backup()
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\mani\Desktop\reference_files\" & _
                    Left(.Name, InstrRev(.Name, ".") - 1) & _
                    "_" & Format(Date(), "ddmmmyyyy") & ".xlsx"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

this one is a bit simple one.

```
Sub Backup()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\mani\Desktop\reference_files\AutoGenerated" & Format(Date, "MMM-DD") & ".xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time and giving me a solution but my requirement was to keep the same file name+Date at different location. In this code it gives "AutoGeneratedMay-26.xlsx" however I wanted to read dynamically. I may not have explained it properly. Thanks again for taking time.